# WordPress issue - data is not showing in wp-admin, but when searching through database, all the data is there

Tags: plugins, php, mysql

I did a couple of plugin updates, and simple updates and it caused a site crash. I was able to deal with the plugin and get back into WP-Admin, but none of the data is there. No pages, events, products, customer orders, no media. But when I search through the database, all the data is there.

I have tried doing a WordPress DB repaid function in wp-config.php, which finds no errors. I have installed a clean copy of WordPress and moved the database and wp-content file over, but still no luck. What would cause the data to be in the database the same way it was before, but now none of the data shows?

Comment: Are you sure your site is connected to the correct database? Do the details in wp-config.php match the details of the database you're looking at?

Comment: @JacobPeattie, yes, I have checked everything. It seems as though a plugin update that was performed yesterday changes all post_type to 'post'. Currently, I am manually going through and updating them one by one but would love a simpler solution.

Comment: Unless that plugin has a way to undo that change you're out of luck. This is why regular backups are important. Perhaps check if your host has a backup from before the update.

Comment: I just went through and updated post_type to what each needed to be. Unfortunately, this site was on a server that wasn't regularly backed up. But, it will be on one of my other servers that have backups now lol.